# POCO C++ and computer sleep and wake up

Tags: c++, sleep, poco-libraries

My problem is like this. I'm creating a service with poco and I'm using network drivers for random operations. The problem is that when machine goes to sleep windows 7 unpludges the network drivers leaving me non-working handlers.  So is there a way to catch a sleep signal with POCO , and do a clean unintialiaze / reinitialize when the machine wakes up ?

Comment: Well you could open a clock and refresh every hour, but that is a very inelegant solution.

Comment: why the emphasis on POCO? I don't see how that is important here.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just detect the connection failure and retry the operation? You should have this anyway.

Network operations can fail for many reasons. Maybe a switch or a router failed. Maybe the remote system suffered a failure and its failover partner has just taken over its IP address.